# A pair of dice rolls and outcome

Tags: probability

A pair of fair dice is rolled three times and each time the two digits are added. What is the probability that a sum that is greater than or equal to 9 occurs exactly once?

My solution:

The ways to get the various totals is:
9 = 5 4, 4 5
9 = 3 6, 6 3
10 = 5 5
10 = 6 4, 4 6
11 = 5 6, 6 5
12 = 6 6

There are 10 ways to roll to get a sum of >= 9.
There are 36 different outcomes for each roll.

The probability of getting a sum of >= 9 is 10/36.
The probability of not getting a sum of < 9 is 26/36.

So for 3 rolls for a pair of dice, the probability of getting sum of >= 9 is

$3.(10/36).(26/36).(26/36)$

Correct?

Comment: Yes, you have done it the right way. Should have said towards the end "$\dots$ getting sum of $\ge 9$ *exactly once* $\dots$."

Comment: There is a wording issue in your answer, you should have written "the probability that the sum is not $\ge 9$ is $26/36$." But that is what you meant. Please note that your answer of $(3)(10/36)(26/36)^2$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In words:

- Choose $1$ out of $3$ events for which the sum is greater than or equal to $9$
- Choose $2$ out of the remaining $2$ events for which the sum is smaller than $9$

---

Mathematically, it can be expressed as $\binom{3}{1} \cdot P(sum\geq9) \cdot \binom{2}{2} \cdot P(sum<9)$

- $\binom{3}{1} = \frac{3!}{1!2!} = 3$
- $\binom{2}{2} = \frac{2!}{2!0!} = 1$
- $P(sum\geq9) = P([3,6],[4,5],[4,6],[5,4],[5,5],[5,6],[6,3],[6,4],[6,5],[6,6]) = \frac{10}{36}$
- $P(sum<9) = 1-P(sum\geq9) = \frac{26}{36}$

So the answer is $3 \cdot \frac{10}{36} \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{26}{36} = \frac{65}{108}$

Comment: The answer is currently not right.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Yep, I agree; Now fixed; Thanks

Comment: @Jaysun: Please note revised answer...

Comment: @barak, noted, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a Bernoulli trial. and the formula is:nCk*(p^k)*(1-p)^(n-k). 3C1=3

So the answer is 3*(10/36)*(26/36)^2 which is exactly the same as you wrote.

[Here is the link to wikipedia "Bernoulli Trial"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial)

Comment: for a similar question where you wanted a sum greater than or equal to 9 exactly twice, would the answer then be; 3*(10/36)^2(26/36)?